# MasterPagefile configured in web.config but I want a page without it and can't get rid of warning

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, master-pages

So I usually put my masterpagefile tag in my web.config (in VS2013)

```
<pages validateRequest="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="Static" masterPageFile="~/Site.Master"></pages>
```

In my solution, I want to put a plain html page (which doesn't include a MasterPageFile tag).

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Error.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.ErrorPage" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>ddd</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

By doing nothing, I get the warning:

Validation (XHTML5): Content is not supported outside 'script' or 'asp:content' regions

Now, I can get rid of the error by adding a blanked out MasterPageFile to my page declaration

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="" CodeBehind="Error.aspx.cs" Inherits=".Web.ErrorPage" %>
```

but that ends up giving me the warning

Validation (ASP.Net): This attribute requires a value.  If the value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the MasterPageFile attribute altogether?

Comment: Yes, in my little html example, there is not MasterPageFile tag which causes the asp:content warning.

Comment: When you added this new file, did you click WebForm or ContentPage? I know I have this problem when I'm adding a new item with ContentPage, I'm unable to remove the MasterPageFile for whatever reason, but when I use WebForm, then it does not attach itself to a MasterPageFile.

Comment: I just did a test with a new file and I did pick WebForm.  I still get the warning.  At least the warning only appears if the .aspx file is open.

Comment: That's a new one to me. Is it just a warning or an actual error that won't let you compile? If it's just a warning, I think you should be okay.

Comment: It's just a warning so I can just ignore it in the end.